# Dynamically Get File Names In a Folder in my website server ( ftp )

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have uploaded some files such as file1.pdf and file2.pdf and ... on my webserver -> `ftp.MYWEBSITE.net\wwwroot\myfiles\`

Now I want to get all these file names and show them on my website dynamically,

for example when client goes to address www.MYWEBSITE.com he could see all files names in a list !

Note that MYWEBSITE is uploaded to `wwwroot\mywebsite\default.aspx`

should i use ftp connection with ftp userid and password ? or i can directly go to \myfiles path without creating new ftp connection ?

should i use any control in asp.net ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code for it:

```
 void GetFiles()
        {
            DirectoryInfo d= new DirectoryInfo(strFolderPath);
            var files = d.GetFiles("*.pdf*");
            FileInfo[] subfileInfo = files.ToArray<FileInfo>();

            if (subfileInfo.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < subfileInfo.Length; j++)
                {
                    bool isHidden = ((File.GetAttributes(subfileInfo[j].FullName) & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden);
                    if (!isHidden)
                    {
                        string strExtention = th.GetExtension(subfileInfo[j].FullName);
                        if (strExtention.Contains("pdf"))
                        {                            
                            string path = subfileInfo[j].FullName;
                            string name = bfileInfo[j].Name;                           
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

if both your ftp and website are on the same server, you can read the list of the files using the file object in .net library and bind it to a repeater control in ASP.NET

you can use `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` objects for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use FTP.

1. Configure enable parent paths: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524697%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

   <system.web>
   <asp enableParentPaths="true">
   </system.web>
2. Get the path:
   string strFolderPath = Server.MapPath("~/../myfiles");
3. Use the code provided by Arshad

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient("ftp://localhost", "ftpUser", "ftpPass");
        List<string> files = client.DirectoryListing();
        foreach (string s in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class FTPClient
{
  // The hostname or IP address of the FTP server
  private string _remoteHost;

  // The remote username
  private string _remoteUser;

  // Password for the remote user
  private string _remotePass;

  public FTPClient(string remoteHost, string remoteUser, string remotePassword)
  {
    _remoteHost = remoteHost;
    _remoteUser = remoteUser;
    _remotePass = remotePassword;
  }


  public List<string> DirectoryListing()
  {
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_remoteHost);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_remoteUser, _remotePass);
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        result.Add(reader.ReadLine());
    }

    reader.Close();
    response.Close();
    return result;
 }
```

}